# How to add to numpy arrays based on conditional output from a function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given these dataframes (in the actual data, there can be millions of rows in each):

df1 =

```
   Start  End
0     10   20
1     25   35
```

df2 =

```
   Start  End
0     12   18
1      2    8
2     22   28
```

Where `df1` can be considered the master ranges and `df2` are sample ranges, where I need to store the offsets for each range in `df2` as a set of columns. With help from [sammywemmy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60844078/452587) I was able to get an output with the offsets:

```
# Import required modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Define dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20], [25, 35]], columns=['Start', 'End'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[12, 18], [2, 8], [22, 28]], columns=['Start', 'End'])

# Create 2d numpy arrays
np_start1 = df1['Start'].to_numpy()
np_end1 = df1['End'].to_numpy()
np_start2 = df2['Start'].to_numpy()
np_end2 = df2['End'].to_numpy()

# Use numpy tiles to create shapes that allow elementwise math
tile_start1 = np.tile(np_start1, (len(df2), 1)).T
tile_end1 = np.tile(np_end1, (len(df2), 1)).T
tile_start2 = np.tile(np_start2, (len(df1), 1))
tile_end2 = np.tile(np_end2, (len(df1), 1))

# Do some math
np_start1_end2_diff = np.subtract(tile_start1, tile_end2)
np_start2_end1_diff = np.subtract(tile_start2, tile_end1)
np_start2_start1_diff = np.subtract(tile_start2, tile_start1)
np_end2_end1_diff = np.subtract(tile_end2, tile_end1)

# Create columns
col_start1_end2_diff = [f'S1-E2_{i}' for i in range(len(df2))]
col_start2_end1_diff = [f'S2-E1_{i}' for i in range(len(df2))]
col_start2_start1_diff = [f'S2-S1_{i}' for i in range(len(df2))]
col_end2_end1_diff = [f'E2-E1_{i}' for i in range(len(df2))]

# Create dataframes of calculated numpy arrays
df_start1_end2_diff = pd.DataFrame(np_start1_end2_diff, columns=col_start1_end2_diff)
df_start2_end1_diff = pd.DataFrame(np_start2_end1_diff, columns=col_start2_end1_diff)
df_start2_start1_diff = pd.DataFrame(np_start2_start1_diff, columns=col_start2_start1_diff)
df_end2_end1_diff = pd.DataFrame(np_end2_end1_diff, columns=col_end2_end1_diff)

# Lump calculated numpy arrays into output dataframe
df_output = pd.concat([
    df_start1_end2_diff,
    df_start2_end1_diff,
    df_start2_start1_diff,
    df_end2_end1_diff
], axis=1)

# Sort the columns by the digits at the end
filtered = df_output.columns[df_output.columns.str.contains('\d')]
cols = sorted(filtered, key=lambda x: x[-1])
df_output = df_output.reindex(cols, axis='columns')

print(df_output)
```

Output:

```
   S1-E2_0  S2-E1_0  S2-S1_0  E2-E1_0  S1-E2_1  S2-E1_1  S2-S1_1  E2-E1_1  S1-E2_2  S2-E1_2  S2-S1_2  E2-E1_2
0       -8       -8        2       -2        2      -18       -8      -12      -18        2       12        8
1        7      -23      -13      -17       17      -33      -23      -27       -3      -13       -3       -7
```

- S1 = df1.Start
- E1 = df1.End
- S2 = df2.Start
- E2 = df2.End

The part I'm struggling with is that I also need to add an additional column for each row in `df2` based on the output of the following function:

```
def get_position(start1, end1, start2, end2):
    if start1 >= start2 and end1 <= end2:
        return 'A'
    elif start1 > end2:
        return 'B'
    elif start1 == end2:
        return 'C'
    elif start1 < end2 and end1 > end2:
        return 'D'
    elif start1 < start2 and end1 > start2:
        return 'E'
    elif end1 == start2:
        return 'F'
    elif end1 < start2:
        return 'G'
```

The target output should be this:

```
   S1-E2_0  S2-E1_0  S2-S1_0  E2-E1_0  Pos_0  S1-E2_1  S2-E1_1  S2-S1_1  E2-E1_1  Pos_1  S1-E2_2  S2-E1_2  S2-S1_2  E2-E1_2  Pos_2
0       -8       -8        2       -2      A        2      -18       -8      -12      B      -18        2       12        8      G
1        7      -23      -13      -17      B       17      -33      -23      -27      B       -3      -13       -3       -7      A
```

How do I append a `Pos_{i}` column for each row in `df2` that is an output of function `get_position()`?

Is a function with a bunch of if/else conditions even a good idea when we're dealing with millions of rows? I've read that we can [vectorize](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-with-python-turn-your-conditional-loops-to-numpy-vectors-9484ff9c622e) functions to improve performance, but I was not able to figure out how to do that for `get_position()` in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize `get_position()` using [`np.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
def get_position(start1, end1, start2, end2):
    return np.select([
        (start1 >= start2) & (end1 <= end2)
        start1 > end2,
        start1 == end2,
        (start1 < end2) & end1 > end2),
        # etc...
        ], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], '?')
```

Now just invoke it with entire arrays of `start1`, `end1` and so on, instead of individual cells.